# Does someone know why req.file return undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, multer

Does someone know why req.file return undefined? I am making sure I use a image file and idk why but multer keeps doing this to me

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });

app.post("/sign-up", upload.single("icon"), async (req, res) => {
  let html = req.body.data;
  console.log(html);
  if (html.dp !== process.env.devPassword)
    return res.status(400).json({ error: `Incorrect password!` });

  if (!req.file)
    return res.status(400).json({ error: `Please upload an image.` });

  let image = req.file
console.log(image)
  let date = new Date();
  let newdate =
    date.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();

  let data = await profileShema.find().sort({ username: 1 });

  if (data.find((v) => v.username === html.uname.replace(/</g, "&lt;")))
    return res.status(400).json({ error: `That username is already taken.` });

  let newProfile = new profileShema({
    username: html.uname.replace(/</g, "&lt;"),
    password: html.psw.replace(/</g, "&lt;"),
    icon: image.buffer,
    date: `${newdate}`,
    followers: 0,
    discord: null,
    twitter: null,
    author: false,
  }).save();

  return res
    .status(200)
    .json({ success: `${html.uname.replace(/</g, "&lt;")} added!` });
});
```

```
 <form class="modal-content animate" id="FormSignUp" action="/sign-up" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="container">
                <label for="icon"><b>Avatar</b></label>
                <input type="file" id="icon" name="icon" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" required />
                <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" autocomplete="off" required />
                <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required />
                <label for="dp"><b>Developer Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Developer Password" name="dp" required />
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <button type="submit" class="submitbtn">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        
<script>
        const form = document.getElementById("FormSignUp");
        const error = document.getElementById("error");
        const success = document.getElementById("success");

        form.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries());
            console.log(data)
            const response = await fetch("/sign-up", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ data }),
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                // Display success message here
                const successData = await response.json();
                success.innerHTML = `<span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
            <strong>Success!</strong> ${successData.success}`;
                success.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                const errorData = await response.json();
                error.innerHTML = `<span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
        ${errorData.error}`;
                error.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    </script>
```

When I try to upload a file it always returns undefined I'm not sure why, I tried searching for answers but couldn't find anything, also I'm using GitHub so that's why I'm not using /uploads

Comment: `FormData` doesn't have a JSON representation. You should sending the FormData object itself, using `appliction/form-data` content type.

Comment: I tried this but I still get undefined
```const formData = new FormData(form);
  
  
    const response = await fetch("/sign-up", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
            });```

Comment: It should work. If you view the request in the browser console do you see the file being uploaded?

Comment: Are you seeing the other fields in `req.body`?

Comment: Yes I am receiving other fields but icon is always {}.   { icon: {}, uname: 'Test', psw: 'test', dp: 'mypasseord$' }

Comment: That updated code looks correct, I can't think of any reason why you're not getting it.

Comment: The icon will be in `req.file`, not `req.body`.

Comment: Yes I know that returns undefined

Comment: Try adding `"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"` to the `headers` object.

Comment: I added it but nothing I still get undefined const response = await fetch("/sign-up", {
      method: "POST",
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
},      body: formData,
            });